# Posting data from swift to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift

I know this has been gone over before but I've spent hours on this and can't seem to figure out how to post data to a node.js server...  I've started the project using cloud9 and node.js so I know I have a good install and that I'm starting with a working site.

In swift I'm sending a post request like

```
func post (){
    let url = URL(string: "https://the-game-stevens-apps.c9users.io/index.html/")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "name=henry&message=HelloWorld"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Then in my server.js file I have

```
  var router = express();
  router.use(express.urlencoded());
  router.post('/index.html', function(req, res) {
     var obj = {name:req.body.name,text:req.body.message};
  });
```

I have plenty of experience with javascript but I'm a noob when it comes to node.js and have just been poking around with it, any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you please tell me the issue you are facing?

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated the question. I can't figure out how to post data to a node.js server, I keep getting 405 and various other erros as I try different things

Comment: Do you have all the config set for port for node.js service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part I can correct in your node.js code is

To get router you need to call express.Router();

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
  router.use((req,res,next) => {
      console.log("/" + req.method,  "host"+ req.host, "Params" + req.params);
      next();
  });

  router.post('/index.html', (req, res) => {
         const obj = {name:req.body.name,text:req.body.message};
        //insert obj into database
  });
```

Comment: I couldn't tell you exactly what I did but I got it working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. To your OP that’s the solution. Please do upvote and accept the answer if it helped resolving the issue

Comment: I think I kept fluctuating between getting it to work and breaking it and getting random errors because once I started logging the output and tweaked the code a bit the posted data started coming though